# Is there really no way to just have 'audio output = screen output' work as expected. (Windows 10, multiple screens)

Tags: windows-10, audio, multiple-monitors

I have connected a second screen with built in speakers to just watch YouTube.

I would like audio for programs on this screen to be sent out the speakers on this screen, but have found this is difficult to achieve.

I have to mess around with the settings, but can't really get them right.

I've found per-app output, and this makes sense for apps like Spotify, but I want something like *per screen output*.

**To clarify** (instead of rant):
I just want to watch content in chrome (mainly YouTube). Sometimes on the TV, sometimes on the monitor. **How do I conveniently switch chrome audio output from TV to monitor and back?** (Because the bugger is not capable of recognizing which screen it is on ;-) ) Preferrably, other 'apps' should always output to the speakers.

Comment: Computers are not rational beings ;) Your request is rather edge-case for anyone to have already written it in at OS-level. Few people have multiple screens with speakers in, so few people have it as a requirement. Personally, I've been using dual screens for 25 years & have never thought about needing that.

Comment: Computers are explicitly rational things. The problem is that they are programmed by marginally rational beings with limited budgets and even more limited time. Edge cases take time to work out and work around that may well be better spent elsewhere.

Comment: Good philosophy stuff. I wonder if it just works on Mac, though. 

These devs... yeah... pretty consistent. I wonder if I ever met one that did not find strange excuses when I reported a bug.

Comment: It doesn't work on Mac either. You can output per app, but not per window or per Space; & Spaces & displays are not tied to each other.

Comment: How are you playing music? Do you double-click on icons or files, or do you have one player running which opens the files? When and how is an app assigned to a screen?

Comment: Wat? 1. I'm not playing music, I was just acknowledging that it makes sense to have a music app output to a certain audio device. 2. An app (or rather chrome in my case) is displayed on one of two screens, don't make it harder than it is.

Answer (score 3):

On your taskbar on the bottom, click on the volume icon. Above it should be a name and if you click on that if gives you an option to change your audio output if you have multiple audio devices.
[image: T]
For example, in this screenshot you can see since my headphones are connected to my computer via bluetooth I can switch between its audio and my normal computer audio.

If this doesn't work, I would suggest going into volume mixer and see if your monitor shows up. If you can provide clarification, how is your tv connected to your computer?

EDIT: If you are using chromecast or something connected via wifi or bluetooth, you could just disable your wi-fi or bluetooth then enable it again so it resets.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general way to make Chrome (or any other app) aware on which screen
it is being displayed, and whether that monitor also has a sound output.
But there are utilities that help easily switching apps from one sound device to
another.

Below is a list of free products that might help:

- [**Audio Router**](https://github.com/audiorouterdev/audio-router)
  Enhances the Windows audio mixer to also switch outputs.

  [image]
- [**Audio Pick**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/audiopick/gfhcppdamigjkficnjnhmnljljhagaha?hl=en)
  Chrome extension to pick a default audio output device.
  Only works for HTML5  and  elements served via HTTP(S).
- [**Voicemeeter Banana**](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) (donationware)
  An advanced audio mixer application that installs a virtual audio device
  that it controls.
- [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
  An advanced keyboard macro utility with which you may program hotkeys to carry
  out unlimited operations. Use it to do repetitive actions with one key-press.

Comment: +1 for AHK. All you need for logic is window location (`WinGetPos`) and grab a script to set the audio device for a process like the answer here: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=32900

Comment: Posting my thoughts about AHK would result in insta-ban. The Audio Pick looked extremely promising, indeed it promises to do exactly what I want, but unfortunately it does nothing.

Comment: AHK in addition to any other solution that works for you would be painless. I admit that I rather like AHK.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows 7 or 10?  It seems like 10.  If so...

1. Go to Settings (Home) > System > Sound.
2. Scroll to bottom.
3. Click on "App volume and device preferences"
4. There you can select individual outputs for different apps.

I'm not sure if this will be persistent but you'll have to test.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thx for trying, but I already found this, and it is persistent and annoying. Reason: When I set Chrome (where youtube is running) to output to the TV, I can no longer hear anything on the web when the TV is off and I browse something else on the main display.

Answer (score 0):

- Windows systray: 3 clicks
- [SoundSwitch systray](https://soundswitch.aaflalo.me/): 2 clicks
  **or** Ctrl-Alt-F11 (which also shows the OSD in the screenshot).
  In the settings you can only enable devices that should be shown (the 2nd Jabra "Hands-Free" profile with worse audio quality for example does't make sense).

[image: systray]
[image: OSD]
[image: settings]

- [Tools for older Windows versions](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/easily-change-or-switch-the-default-audio-sound-output-in-windows-vista-and-xp/)

Comment: So, you are telling me that I can change the default audio output device with 3 clicks. Solid advice. Oh, I can *save one click* by using "software". Great.

Comment: As you asked about "conveniently": saving one click with an alternative of doing it with the keyboard is better than nothing until your AHK script is working. btw i am using a simple [ASWITCH-3](https://www.amazon.com/Hq-Stereo-Input-Control-ASWITCH-3/dp/B000I8OOS8) to change from the computer speakers to the stereo.